# How can I centralize my brand + name with my pages?

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap to create my navbar but I am having a problem.
My brand img and brand img is not aligned with my pages names...
[image]

I would like the brand img and name Ghiro to be aligned with "Home" "Products" "Services" "About us".

This is my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg brand-colors">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
<img src="../../assets/images/ghiro-logo-no-shadow.png" width="50" height="50">
<h5 class="navbar-brand">Ghiro</h5>
</a>

<button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">Home</a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
<a routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link" routerLink="/products">Products</a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="/services">Services</a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about-us">About us</a>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

I am new at programming and could not fix this. If anyone can help me I appreciate.
I am building this website for a friend and I am going to use as my portfolio at the end.
I will post on my github and put the website live.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To change the style of your website you have to use css. To do that there are 2 different options, first you create a new file and link it in your  tag in your html file or second write it directly in your "html code" (also in  tag). Here an example of the second method:

```
<head>

    <!-- Here is your css code -->
    <style>

        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: sans-serif; /* here you can set your favorite font family */
        }

        nav{
            background-color: white; /* set the background color in your navbar to white */
            padding-top: 10px;
            min-height: 70px;
            border-bottom: black 3px solid; /* if you want to have a border under your navbar */
            align-items: center;
        }

        .nav-item{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 20px;
            display: inline-block; /* brings all of your li (nav-item) in one line */
            list-style: none;
            float: right;
        }

        .navbar-brand{
            float: left;
        }

        h5{
            padding-right: 50px;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg brand-colors">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <img src="../../assets/images/ghiro-logo-no-shadow.png" width="50" height="50">
            <h5 class="navbar-brand">Ghiro</h5>
        </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
                    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">Home</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link" routerLink="/products">Products</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
                    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/services">Services</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
                    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about-us">About us</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

try this one and test some things in the " part" to customize it, I just don't want to do the whole stuff, this is just to give you some idea.